# How to understand the bytes in the executable and relate to load of program into memory?

Tags: assembly, load, executable, dos

The following is close to my question, still I have a missing link, that would help me understand the loading process.

[How does DOS load a program into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715618/how-does-dos-load-a-program-into-memory)

My question is "what will happen in machine step by step when I type mf.com in commandline?"

I am using windows 7 and I have installed NASM for compiling.
The following is the assembly that I got in one of the website

The filename is mf.asm

---

org 100h

mov dx, msg
mov ah, 9

int 21h
ret

msg db "Hello, world !$"

---

I used the following command to get My mf.com file

> nasm -f bin mf.asm -o mf.com

Now, I run the mf.com by typing

> mf.com

I get the result
Hello, World  !$

I opened the mf.com binary in textpad and its shown like this.

---

```
   0: BA 08 01 B4 09 CD 21 C3  48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 77  ********Hello, w
  10: 6F 72 6C 64 20 21 24                              orld !$
```

---

The ******** were the respecive characters tha was showed in the text editors.

what will happen in machine step by step when I type mf.com in commandline and hit enter?
especially "BA 08 01 B4 09 CD 21 C3" how would this 8 bytes be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the bytes that represent the instruction's themselves, Prefix bytes (up to 4 I believe), primary opcode (1 or 2), optional MODRM and SIB bytes, displacement bytes, and finally the immediate operands (if any). The machine interprets those bytes depending on the prefix and the primary opcode of the instruction. If you really want to find out you can find tables that show you what those are in binary.

Processors don't interpret the instructions as mnemonics, the mnemonics are only their so it's easier for you to write the code. These mnemonics are changed by the compiler into something the computer can understand which is bytecode or raw binary data. The hardware takes over from that point.

Comment: Please let me know, where can I find this table?

Comment: Thanks Ramos, here is what I interpreted.

Comment: •build a DOS EXEC parameter block (see http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/it/90/15.html ) (includes information on environment variables, command lines arguments, FCBs and register values on return)
•free up all memory the calling program isn't using
•setup calling argument registers 
•ah = 4Bh ('EXEC' service type)
•al = 00h ('load and execute' function)
•ds:dx -> program name
•es:bx -> ptr to exec parameter block
•call interrupt 21h
•on return reset stack pointer and test for errors.
•copy entire .com file into memory
•setup register values

Comment: •AL,AH drive letter status
 •CS,DS,ES,SS -> PSP segment
 •SP = offset of last word available in first 64k segment
•jump to IP=100h

Comment: BA 08 01 -> Load DX Memoryblock @ 8th byte (what is 1?)

Comment: B4 09 -> AH-to-9 is direction to display
CD 21 -> intrerrupt call , makes Data(@DX) to display (until it finds $ else lots of junk could even be shown)
http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm

Comment: Some of this is DOS specific and my specialty is *nix based systems Assembly so I can't say for sure what some of those values are.

Answer (score 1):

The characters `BA 08 01 B4 09 CD 21 C3  48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 77` are machine code. They would be translated into assembly instructions. From your program, they are the translation of the following code:

```
mov dx, msg mov ah, 9

int 21h ret
```

So, in a nutshell those 8 bytes cause `MOV` and `INT` instructions to be executed in your processor. The MOV instructions copies the address of memory location in DX register which contains the string "Hello World !$".