# Loading and unloading executable

Tags: assembly, dos, interrupt

I have a problem. I need to load a .com file into memory do something and then unload it. I'm going to use `int 21 ah=4bh` and `al=1`, which will do everything I need, and give me enough information for future manual execution of this file. After execution I need to unload file from memory, but I don't know how to do this. 
I don't use any assemblers, I'm writing in HEX, but I will be glad, if you'll advice me something, I could use to compile native MS-DOS x16 .com

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715618/how-does-dos-load-a-program-into-memory) question could be related. As the answer there says COM files are extremely simple files, so unless you're interested in the PSP (located in the first 256 bytes of the code segment when you run a COM file) you can just manipulate the file directly (remembering that the code is loaded at 0x100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use LZASM for this:

http://protools.winasm.net/lzasm.html

It would probably be easier to use Turbo Pascal 3.0 to create .COM files which is freely available from:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20792

Comment: Well, I have to use asm, bu I'll thhink about Pascal, as I remember, it allows to use asm code