# 8086 - what is the default adress of data segment

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm just confused why we should initialize the DS register going with all this :

```
data segment
msg1 db 10,13, "saisir le premier digit:$"
data ends
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax`
```

when the first variable is stored its stored on data segment
so isn't already ds=data
why we should initialize ds=data if they already the same

Comment: Is this a DOS `.EXE` program. If so by default when the DOS loader loads an executable (`.EXE`) it sets _DS_ (and _ES_) to the segment where the [PSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) is. DS:0 and ES:0 point to the base of the PSP. You need to explicitly set _DS_ to the segment containing the data.

Comment: Appears this question may be closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715618/how-does-dos-load-a-program-into-memory

Answer (score 1):

> when the first variable is stored its stored on data segment

I think there's a misconception. You need to make a distinction between the compile-time and the run-time.

It was your compiler (assembler) that put the *msg1* text in the data section of your program. We don't actually call this **storing a variable** and furthermore there's no particular setting of the `DS` segment register involved.

However at run-time, when you want to retrieve or store these variables, the `DS` segment register needs to point at the data section. Since at program start this is not the case, it's up to you to do that explicitly.

```
1 data segment
2 msg1 db 10,13, "saisir le premier digit:$"
3 data ends
4 mov ax,data
5 mov ds,ax
```

Do note that the execution didn't start at the 1st line of this snippet of code, but rather at the 4th! That's another way to see that there wasn't any prior *store on the data segment*.