# DOS COMMAND.COM load / exec program (int 21h / ah=4B) keeps data until program returns?

Tags: dos

I was reading a very cool post "How does DOS load a program into memory?"

[How does DOS load a program into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715618/how-does-dos-load-a-program-into-memory)

to bring some light on doubts about the process of loading and executing a program in DOS. It is clear as the water but I still have a doubt:

Once the COMMAND.COM has issued (called) the INT 21h interrupt, what happens to the "parameters" such as the program's file name? Are they kept until the called program exits (returns) or they are immediatly discarded after INT 21h is called?

I mean, for example, the program's file name pointed by DS:DX, i.e. 'C:\HOMEWORK\TEXT01.COM', is it preserved in memory until the executed program exits or it is freed immediatly and that memory is reused (overwritten)?

Note: I know that registers and pointers will change, but what happens to the string once the executed program is running?

Thx!

Comment: The string will be available as a command line argument for the entire life time of the application , but I'm not sure if it's copied and passed or just pointed at.